# Trying to format a Computer that has the admin account and permissions deleted

Tags: windows

I am an administrator for a business and have inherited windows 7 guest computers. They are pretty much soft locked to where the only thing that can be done is surf the web.  I have no administrator profile, no command prompt or any permission that would allow me to update or format. Is there anyway that i can format these computers without administrator access or the command prompt?

Comment: Define what you mean by "format these computers"

Comment: I meant to wipe them clean, and do a fresh install of Windows 10, as i do not have the original windows 7 discs.  I have recently taken over this position and am picking up pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Boot the computer using the bootable Windows 7 Setup Disc. Repartition and reformat from the Setup application.

You will need this disc after a format in all cases.

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have access to any of these disks, as whoever set them up before i started did not leave them.  I thought i could maybe do a windows 10 upgrade for free, but since these CPU's pretty much have no permissions to do anything i thought i could wipe them, then install Windows 10 from a drive.

Comment: @DamonA - You cannot solve this problem without a Windows 7 installation disk.  Download one if you don't have one.  Of course formatting the machine isn't really required in a case like this.